# CSS animation tricky bug in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
    from {  opacity: 1; }
    to {  opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from {  opacity: 0; }
    to {  opacity: 1; }
}
.intro-text-0 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear 1s,
        fade-out 1s linear 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.intro-text-1 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear 2s,
        fade-out 1s linear 4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And the simple HTML code:

```
<div class="intro-text-0">Hello</div>
<div class="intro-text-1">Holla</div>
```

When I run it, "Hello" appear in 1 second and in 3 seconds instead of fading out for 1 second, it fades out instantly. Here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3er6y0df/

I tried switching it to this:

```
.intro-text-0 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear 2s,
        fade-out 1s linear 4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And it works perfectly.

I must mention, that this bug appeared only in Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.120 Built on Debian 7.6, running on Debian 7.7 (281580) (64-bit)), I check it out in Firefox and IE11 and there is no problem there.

Comment: I tried to create a reduced test case out of your issue and reported it at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431580.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented a bit and found a much simpler solution:

```
-webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear 1001ms,
    fade-out 1s linear 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Using 1001ms instead 1s (=1000ms) will not be noticed by a regular human eye :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a bugfix though it could be a alternative.

Instead of animating a element with keyframes + animation on the elements itself why not put it all in the keyframe animation?

```
@keyframes AnimateMe {
  0%   { opacity:0%; }
  80% { opacity:100%; }
  100% { opacity:0%; }
}
```