# Frontend glitch when using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I added a few charts on a static html page set up with bootstrap, which worked fine. After migrating to react I got a weird react frontend glitch which is shown in the following images...

Image 1 shows how this looks while scrolling and a short amount of time after scrolling ended.

[image: During Scrolling]

After scrolling ended the page gets rerendered and shows up correctly. I calculate the chart inputs only once when the subcomponents get rendered. Scrolling does not lead to a re-render.

[image: After Scrolling]

Comment: can you recreate this bug in a snippet here on SO?

Comment: Is this affecting all browsers or just Chrome? I'm wondering if it's a browser rendering bug, not a React bug. Are there any scroll animations? I once found a trick to force hardware acceleration and resolve _some_ chrome render bugs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905941/blinking-fixed-header-in-site-with-scrolling-animation/20907500#20907500

Comment: Confirmed! Its seems like a Chrome Bug. The solution didn't work, but something similar! Thank you anyway. I post the solution in an own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is caused of [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). The accepted solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621891/css-animation-tricky-bug-in-chrome) did the trick:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear 1001ms, fade-out 1s linear 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```